# Using two filters in series

Tags: circuit-analysis

I know my question is a bit broad, but I haven't found the answer to this question. As a work for university , i am asked to use an oscillator that produces a triangle wave and after that use two active filters (one band-pass and one second order low pass) so that the triangle waves becomes a sine wave . I haven't quite understood , **why would two filters be needed and not only one that can do the same job and that question is in general not only for my circuit** . I am going to be posting some photos of the schematic just for reference (Ι have highlighted the parts that my question is based upon)  [image]

Comment: it seems that the first op amp is missing a connection

Comment: @jstola its a first design yes I missed it while designing though the question remains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this answer to be compact I will define a new function.

$$
tri(x) = \text{abs}\Biggl(\biggl(\bigl(x-1\bigr) \mod 4\biggr)-2\Biggr)-1
$$

And it looks like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=abs(((x-1)%20mod%204)-2)-1,%20plot%20from%20-4%20to%204):

[image]

And you want to get this sine out of it, which looks like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=abs(((x-1)%20mod%204)-2)-1,%20(sin(x*pi%2F2)*2%2Fpi),%20plot%20from%20-4%20to%204):

[image]

In order to do that, you can just simply apply a LP (low pass) filter. Then the higher frequencies required to make the peak of the triangle wave will be removed, and you'll be left with your sine wave.

But wait a second, there's **one term** that a LP filter passes through that is most certainly unwanted. That is the DC term, the 0 Hz. In the above image the DC term is 0 so everything works fine. But in reality there will be some offsets here and there, so in reality it might look like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=abs(((x-1)%20mod%204)-2)-0.5,%20(sin(x*pi%2F2)*2%2Fpi%2B0.5),%20plot%20from%20-4%20to%204):

[image]

With only a LP filter, you will get something similar to the sine wave above. A sine wave with a DC offset. Depending on how your instrument will be used, it might be wanted, but in most cases it is not wanted.

This can be solved with a simple DC-blocking capacitor, it will work as a HP (high pass) filter. But if your frequency is very low, in the 50 Hz region, then that capacitor will have to be pretty big, or small with high gain. A LP filter followed by a HP filter will together work like a BP (band pass) filter. Iff the LP filter's cutoff frequency is higher than the HP filter's cutoff frequency.

So if the end product is a BP filter, then you might as well use a BP filter instead of a HP filter. This will give you yet another LP filter inside the BP filter, so in *some* sense you will have 3rd order LP filter and a 1st order HP filter. That's better than a 2nd order LP filter and a 1st order HP filter.

---

If I were making this for myself as a hobbyist,then I wouldn't care about 3rd order LP vs 2nd order LP. I would just use [this](https://cdn.instructables.com/F3X/LMSH/HSBWO2N5/F3XLMSHHSBWO2N5.MEDIUM.jpg) circuit instead.

Answer (score 0):

As above, one way to convert a triangle wave into a sine wave is to filter off the high-order harmonics and leave the fundamental relatively untouched.  The problem is that while a (perfect) triangle wave has only odd-order harmonics, that third harmonic has over 10% of the amplitude of the fundamental, and is less than two octaves away in the spectrum.

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Audio/geowv.html

The lowpass filter cutoff frequency must be between the fundamental and the third harmonic.  The closer it is to the fundamental, the more it attenuates the harmonics and cleans up the waveform, but as it gets closer to the fundamental it attenuates it more, decreasing the output signal amplitude.  There are many different kinds of multi-pole filter designs, and some are better than others depending on what the output signal is used for.

The reason for a three pole lowpass filter (combined in your two stages) is that it attenuates the third harmonic much more than a single-pole.  It attenuates all of the other harmonics more also, but it is the third that contributes most to the "pointiness" of the triangle shape.  If the filter corner freq is parked right on the fundamental, then a single pole filter attenuates the third harmonic by 65% (9 dB); a three pole filter attenuates it by 95% (27 dB).